# MPI_Isend to non-listening process

Tags: c++, mpi

At some point in my program I'm using `MPI_Isend` to announce all the other processes of some event, but some of them aren't listening and that's perfectly fine. I've tested this situation and it seems to finish ok.

Is it ok if I do this? Am I supposed to retain the request param from every single Isend and cancel it after a certain time if it hasn't been delivered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably retain and cancel requests that aren't going to complete, if not for scalability's sake, then just on general principle. Ideally though, you should never even post sends that you know are not going to be received. If you can't tell who's listening and who's not, you may want to reconsider your design.